# Получить ширину со скролбаром | Javascript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте , уважаемые знатоки !
Подскажите пожалуйста , как узнать ширину окна со скроллбаром в Javascript (макс. кроссбраузерно)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339377/how-to-get-screen-width-without-minus-scrollbar

Comment: Судя по всему там рабочий вариант только на jQuery (

Comment: Там и на Jquery, и на чистом JS. Вот пример: https://jsbin.com/jomiru/4/edit?css,console,output

Comment: Прошу прощения, видимо надо пойти отдыхать , но я что то не вижу там варианта на чистом JS - который показывал размер окна с скроллбаром.

Я наблюдаю там кнопку "TOGGLE SCROLLBAR" и нажав её , значения меняются , а не должны.

Comment: Почему же не должны? При появлении скролл-бара ширина окна становится меньше. А еще там есть кнопка "Run with JS".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например (считаем со скролбаром и без него)

```
body, html
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
}

div
{
height: 1500px;
}
```

JS

```
var widths = 'viewport width (body.scrollWidth): ' 
    + document.body.scrollWidth + '<br />'
    + 'window.innerWidth: ' + window.innerWidth + '<br />';

document.getElementById( 'widths' ).innerHTML = widths;
```

HTML

```
<div id="widths"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/5j3bY/

Comment: А как быть с IE8- ?

Comment: var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth; - примерно так

Comment: Вот тут все для IE8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173236/window-innerheight-ie8-alternative/18136089#18136089